# What are "arguments" in python

Tags: python, arguments

I am new to python and I am reading an online book. There is a chapter which explains the arguments of what they are and when they are used but I don't understand the explanations that well. Can anyone explain better what arguments are?
And please try to explain as simple as you can, because I am a beginner and English is not my native language

Comment: Which book were you reading? Any online link/resource?

Comment: Command line arguments, or arguments to a function?

Comment: SudiptaChatterjee  Learn Python The Hard Way
@DavidHeffernan i need the basic concept of what an argument is in python.

Comment: OK, but first we need to determine what you are talking about. Command line arguments, or arguments to a function?

Comment: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 9):

An argument is simply a value provided to a function when you call it:

```
x = foo( 3 )         # 3 is the argument for foo
y = bar( 4, "str" )  # 4 and "str" are the two arguments for bar
```

Arguments are usually contrasted with parameters, which are names used to specify what arguments a function will need when it is called. When a function is called, each parameter is assigned one of the argument values.

```
# foo has two named parameters, x and y
def foo ( x, y ):
    return x + y

z = foo( 3, 6 )
```

`foo` is given two arguments, 3 and 6. The first argument is assigned to the first parameter, `x`. The second argument is assigned to the second parameter, `y`.

Comment: I don't agree with the expression "each parameter is assigned one of the argument values". It is assigned to one of the argument objects. Assignements are done between an identifier (here called parameter) and an object. A value is one of the constituent of an object : "Every object has an identity, a type and a value." (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) It's not with the value that the assignement is done, it is with the object.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions have to kinds of parameters.
args (arguments) and kwargs (keyword arguments)
args are required parameters, while kwargs have default values set

The following function takes arg 'foo' and kwarg 'bar'

```
def hello_world(foo, bar='bye'):
    print(foo)
    print(bar)
```

This is how you can call the function

```
>>> hello_world('hello')
hello
>>> hello_world('hello', bar='cya')
hello
cya
```

Comment: For lurkers, it should be pointed out  that arguments are similar to variables EXCEPT that they don't 'exist' at definition time so they can't reference each other in the method definition. So hello_world(foo, bar = 'a') is OK - but hello_world(foo, bar=foo) is not.

Comment: @theodox What is a 'variable' for you ?

Comment: I'm using variable to mean a  named reference to some kind of value: the 'a' in 'a=0' or 'if a > 1 then ....'